# Cordova push notifications in Local Area Network

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I'm using Cordova and Ionic to build my own live-chat application. I want to build it only for Android for now.  My app needs to run in a local area network without Internet. So, my question is how to do push notification when a user send a message to another user in a local area network?

Without Internet, I can't use third party service and I can't figure out how to do it without third party. I know I should maintain a long connection with the server. How can I do this in Cordova?

Comment: you can show offline notification using this [https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin

Comment: Thanks.The real thing that puzzled me a lot is how to maintain a long connection with the chat-server when user exit the app. I want the user to recieve messages even when the app is not run in background. When the long connection recieves a message, then the app can  run again and push a notification to the user.

Comment: you need to create plugin for that manually. you can take reference of app like [xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en)